# bootstrap 4 grid system, first two columns get overlapped on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

With this, I want to achieve stacked columns on mobile devices, but I run on a problem here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row border-top border-bottom border-info">
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-12 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">rb</a>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-3 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">folder</a>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-1 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">modtime</a>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 my-1 ">
img
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">width</a>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">height</a>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">filesize</a>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 my-1 sortable position-relative">
  <a class="position-absolute" href="#">linked</a>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 my-1">
delete?
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

where you can see that the first two columns are overlapped without any particular reason. Why?

Thanks,
Dejan

**UPDATE**
as was mentioned down bellow, positioning was causing the problem, thanks all for contributing

Comment: Is this one gonna be a navigation bar?

Comment: this is navbar ..? and why r u putting class `position-relative` and `position-absolute`

Comment: @KiranMistry, thanks for mentioning so that was causing the problem, after all, I could guess so, but I was in a hurry. No, it isn't a navbar it is a way for me to place icons over actual text, but that is another story, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use with `col` class only for that don't put extra **CSS** class on it. It will create a problem here is what u want without overlapping to each other simply use this code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row border-top border-bottom border-info">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#">rb</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">folder</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">modtime</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <p>
    img
    </p>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">width</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
   <a href="#">height</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">filesize</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">linked</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>
    delete?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

if u want on navbar then simply use this code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">rb</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">folder</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">modtime</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">img</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">width</a>
                 <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">height</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">
filesize</a>
                   <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">linked</a>
                   <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">delete?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row border-top border-bottom border-info">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#">rb</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">folder</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">modtime</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <p>
    img
    </p>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">width</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
   <a href="#">height</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">filesize</a>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
    <a href="#">linked</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>
    delete?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">rb</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">folder</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">modtime</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">img</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">width</a>
                 <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">height</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">
filesize</a>
                   <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">linked</a>
                   <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" tabindex="-1">delete?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit or preview [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gvkt3pux/)

More about Bootstrap 4 [Grid System Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

More about Bootstrap 4 Navbar [Code and Example Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php)